# glGenTextures Returning Existing Texture Name

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, textures

I'm on iOS 6.1.4, OpenGL ES 2, and am experiencing strange behavior with `glGenTextures` returning texture "names" which have previously been returned by `glGenTextures`.

Specifically, at initialization time, I iterate through my textures and make OpenGL aware of them, like this:

```
// Generate the OpenGL texture objects
for (Object3D *object3D in self.objects3D)
{
    [self installIntoOpenGLObject3D:object3D];
}

- (void)installIntoOpenGLObject3D:(Object3D *)object3D
{
    GLuint nID;
    glGenTextures(1, &nID);

    Texture *texture = object3D.texture;
    texture.identifier = nID;
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, nID);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, [texture width], [texture height], 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)[texture pngData]);
    ARLogInfo(@"Installed texture '%@' with OpenGL identifier %d", texture.name, texture.identifier);
}
```

At this time, I see texture names like `1, 2, 3, ... n` as expected.

However, sometime later (after an asynchronous network call returns) I create new textures and call `installIntoOpenGLObject3D:` to install them. It is at this later time when I see `glGenTextures` returning names which were issued previously. Obviously this causes the app to render the incorrect texture.

The docs, http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGenTextures.xml , suggest that:

> Texture names returned by a call to glGenTextures are not returned by subsequent calls, unless they are first deleted with glDeleteTextures.

and I'm making no calls to `glDeleteTextures`; however the docs also say:

> it is guaranteed that none of the returned names was in use immediately before the call to glGenTextures.

which is confusing, since it implies that the returned names could be the same if they were not "in use." To my understanding, by calling `glBindTexture` for the texture satisfies the "in use" notion, but, something is wrong.

Another thought I had was perhaps the `EAGLContext` was changing somewhere between the first set of calls to `glGenTextures` but, alas, stepping through in the debugger tells me the context is not changing.

As a (perhaps foolish) hackish workaround I attempted to ensure the texture names were unique myself, as you can see below, however I simply end up with a texture name which I do not track, but also still represents a different texture, so this approach does not provide a workaround:

```
- (void)installIntoOpenGLObject3D:(Object3D *)object3D
{
    if (!self.object3DTextureIdentifiers)
    {
        self.object3DTextureIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set];
    }

    GLuint nID;
    NSNumber *idObj;
    do {
        glGenTextures(1, &nID);
        GLboolean isTexture = glIsTexture(nID);
        idObj = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:nID];
    } while ([self.object3DTextureIdentifiers containsObject:idObj]);

    [self.object3DTextureIdentifiers addObject:idObj];

    Texture *texture = object3D.texture;
    texture.identifier = nID;
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, nID);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, [texture width], [texture height], 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (GLvoid*)[texture pngData]);
    ARLogInfo(@"Installed texture '%@' with OpenGL identifier %d", texture.name, texture.identifier);
}
```

Any thoughts on why `glGenTextures` is returning names which it previously returned?

Comment: Oh, and I forgot to mention that the `glIsTexture` call in the `do while` always returns false.

Comment: Just breezing through your post made me think that you are using multiple threads on which you do this. Could you try to force the later texture loading, to be on the same thread as the first loading and report if the problem persists. (each thread should create its own context and if you wish to share content between contexts you need to use a share-group)

Comment: Thanks Matic. I've double (triple?) checked and the call to `glGenTextures` is always occurring on the main thread.

Answer (score 3):

After much debugging, I believe the root cause to be threading.

While I was certain `glGenTextures` was only being called from one thread (main), it turns out that calls to other OpenGL methods were being called on a different thread. Refactoring so the calls to `glGenTextures` also occur only on that other thread (not-main) seems to address the issue.